# Order of definition matters in Scala?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, companion-object

When looking for implicits, the Scala compiler looks, among other places, in the companion object of the various parts of the classes involved. Apparently, though, it fails to perform this lookup when the implicit conversion is used in the class itself, if it is defined before the companion object. The minimal example I was able to cook up is:

```
trait Counter[A] {
  def count(a: A): Int
}

object Foo {
  def foo[A](a: A)(implicit c: Counter[A]) = c.count(a)
}

case class Bar(id: Int) {
  import Foo._

  def count = foo(this)
}

object Bar {
  implicit object BarCounter extends Counter[Bar] {
    def count(b: Bar) = b.id
  }
}
```

This fails to compile saying `could not find implicit value for parameter c: Counter[Bar]` - I am using Scala 2.9.1.

The interesting thing (suggested by rjsvaljean) is that if we invert the order - that is, we define `object Bar` before `case class Bar` - verything compiles fine.

> Is this a compiler bug? Or I am missing something about the scope rules of Scala?

I should also mention that this problem only arises with implicit resolution. If we explicitly pass the `BarCounter` object, everything compiles fine.

Comment: I don't know why but switching the order of `object Foo` and `case class Foo` makes it not throw the compile error.

Comment: @rjsvaljean Weird - lloks like a compiler glitch. Would you mind adding it as a response so that I can accept it?

Comment: I don't know. Wouldn't it be more useful to edit the question including that data and wait for an answer that explains why it fails to compile instead of how to fix it? Maybe even change the question completely to make it more generic and repost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an actual compiler bug. I have posted it [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6515).